# AWSSDK S3.listObjects() returns an empty object (Node)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to fetch list of objects inside an S3 bucket, but the response is just an empty object `{}`. It seems that I am connecting to the bucket, because if I change bucket's name, not found error is received.

My code:

```
import awsSdk from 'aws-sdk';

const BUCKET = 'bucket-name';
const REGION = 'us-east-1';

export async function readFromBucket(): Promise<void> {
  const s3 = new awsSdk.S3({ region: REGION });

  const res = await s3
    .listObjectsV2({       // tried also listObjects()
      Bucket: BUCKET, 
      Prefix: 'myPrefix/', // tried with and without Prefix
    })
    .promise();
  console.log('RES: ', res); // logs "{}"
}
```

We are using v 2.1179 of awsSdk. I tried using or not using `Prefix` (also giving non-existent one), I tried using both `listObjects()` and `listObjectsV2()`. It does not change the received output. What might be wrong here?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It turned out that my repo was somehow corrupt which was causing this weird issue.